# lsp-java cannot resolve android framework classes

Tags: emacs, android-source

I'm doing some java development on aosp and currently lsp-java cannot find or resolve classes outside the project folder. I'm getting alot of warnings that lsp/flycheck cannot resolve imports such as android.util.Log and android.content.Context, to give two examples.

Is there any way to configure this in lsp-java, either a path to where those classes can be found or SDK file?

Note that I'm not using gradle but pure aosp make files (Android.bp/Android.mk) to compile the apps. I don't need compilation to be supported in lsp but at least the imports should be resolvable, so I can navigate dependencies etc.

I have used ggtags before which is able to resolve such imports, but would prefer to use lsp.

Answer (score 1):

AOSP currently uses `soong`(Android.bp) and `kati`(Android.mk) to describe the compilation relationship.

Unfortunately there is no lsp-java implementation for either of these.

But AOSP is using `bazel` to replace `kati` and `soong`([enter link description here](https://source.android.google.cn/docs/setup/build/bazel/introduction?hl=en)).When the replacement is completed, we can use bazel language server to implement lsp's support for java.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).